# How to get Elements List from WebView in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, webview

I Can Browse webpage by `TWebView` Component in Delphi. Can Fill Elements by javascript command.

Example:

```
WebView1.ExecuteScript( 'document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value = "' + Edit2.Text + '";');
```

How do I get Elements List or Tags List with their attributes (ex. Name, ID, ClassName, ref, ...).

I Googling and read all pages in web but can not found any help for Delphi.

Please Help me.

thanks.

Comment: First please put your Code in code marks. Have you tried using getElementbyTagName('*') like written in that example?
https://delphidabbler.github.io/delphi-tips/tips/56.html

Comment: @fisi-pjm This example is for TWebBrowser Component that suports by IE and not work correctly. I want sample for TWebView Component that suports by Microsoft Edge and work correct for all web pages.